# Is this the fastest way to add multiple rows to a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, sqlcommand

I have a general question that I have not found any answer to. I think it is important to ask this question so I know how to structure the whole application so I am on the right track from the very beginning.

I believe it is practical/efficient to add Multiple rows in one Query command. The below code adds 3 rows with 5 values in 5 columns at once.

See this image also of the table:

[image: Image of DataTable]

My question now is. This table will later have 100,000 columns where I am thinking of for example adding 10 rows at a time. Now imagine that this `cmdString` will be EXTREMELY long.

My question simply is. Is this okay or is this the wrong way to go here when I add so much information in one query? (Is this the fastest way to do it or should I do the below code in another way?)

Thank you!

```
void addMultipleRowWithValuesSQL()
{
    String cmdString = "INSERT INTO DateTimes(DateTime,F1,F2,G1,G2) " + 
                       "VALUES" +
                           "('201005011715','1',2,'3','4')," +
                           "('201005011730','5',6,'7','8')," +
                           "('201005011745','9',10,'11','12');";
 
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmdString))
        {
            try
            {
                comm.Connection = conn;

                conn.Open();
                int i = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (i != 0) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(i + "Rows Added"); 
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex) 
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
            }
        }
    }
}

static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\andre\\source\\repos\\TestDatabaseCreation\\DatabaseTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
}
```

Comment: Having 100000 columns is definitely wrong way and many systems would not even accept that. You should redesign the schema. To the question, you can use some batch insert for fast insertion, make the server parse through piles of text is not good idea.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Based on the picture it's SQL Server, which supports only 1024 columns, ok, up to 30000 in a sparse table :-)

Comment: Does SQL only support 1024 columns. What is a sparse table. Should I then use that if 80% of columns will have a float value and 20% a bool value? If I understand, I must use many tables which I will sync somehow with all those 100,000 columns?

Comment: @Antonin yes, this was what I was afraid of. So `batch insert` is the way to go. I am not familiar of how to do that, but perheps there is an example somewhere then. I thought about that also, that it has to be enormous amount of parsing with such a long string.

Comment: I have trouble to find any good example where I can understand how I can make a `batch insert` of my code example. It would be very useful to see how that could be done? The speed improvement seems to be very big using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They call it **Bulk Insert**, this link here will get you to a nice example that can explain.
[Bulk Insert In SQL Server From C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-insert-in-sql-server-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Usama, Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this link that also showed of how to add multiple rows in one transaction.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/performance-improve-use-batching

My question is if this is a valid and good way to do `batch insert`?
Or does this code also involve enormous amount of parsing like in my original post, if I would add for example 10,000 rows with VALUES for example 200 columns in one transaction?

Just to have a confirmation on that. The code do work to mention.

```
    void addMultipleRowWithValuesSQL()
    {
        List<string> dbOperations = new List<string>();
        dbOperations.Add("INSERT INTO DateTimes(DateTime, F1, F2, G1, G2) VALUES('201005011800', '11', '22', '33', '44');");
        dbOperations.Add("INSERT INTO DateTimes(DateTime, F1, F2, G1, G2) VALUES('201005011815', '55', '66', '77', '88');");
        dbOperations.Add("INSERT INTO DateTimes(DateTime, F1, F2, G1, G2) VALUES('201005011830', '99', '100', '101', '102');");

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

            foreach (string commandString in dbOperations)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn, transaction);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It work, but it's not efficient if the amount of inserted rows are unknown, can be hundreds, but for few insertion you can even make it simpler, using StringBuilder.

Comment: System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("your insert statement, must be ended with semicolon"); sb.Append("another insert statement, must be ended with semicolon"); sb.Append("and another insert statement, must be ended with semicolon"); then you just use this sb in your command to be executed like  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn, transaction); without the need for that foreach.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am familiar with the `StringBuilder` as it is very fast. But I wonder there, even if I use `StringBuilder`, shouldn't it be the same problem that the SQL needs to parse all this if the amount is enormous like 10,000 rows. I might wonder if your solution is better in your answer perheps or will the `StringBuilder` solution be as efficient as your bulk insert/datatable solution?

Comment: Definitely bad to go the List<string> Way and StringBuilder way for anything beyond say 10 simple insert statement, some DBMSs will return an exception if it get too long receiving that much of sql statements.

Comment: That is very good to know. I then wonder if adding 10,000 rows etc. Then your solution in: `Bulk Insert In SQL Server From C#` is a valid and good way to go if I understand?

Comment: Yes the Bulk Insert is the right way, supported by many DBMSs for this exact heavy load situation.

Comment: Usama, that is so great. Thank you for this solution. I will implement the Bulk Insert then. I will mark your post as answer also.

Comment: Great, glad to help.